Will a PC complain if a USB 2 flash drive is powered externally?
TL;DR: How can I power a USB 2 flash drive from an external USB charger (5 V 0.5 A) and not use the power lines of the PC own USB port?
I cannot get smart UPS in my region, and I want my home server to shut down on a longer power loss. Otherwise, if the server doesn't do a clean shutdown, what's the point of even having a UPS?
My idea is to connect a USB flash drive to the home server, but:

Disconnect the power pins from the USB connector.
Connect a USB charger to a mains outlet not covered by the battery backup power.
Connect the 5 V from that charger directly into the USB flash drive.

So that the PC can monitor for the block device presence to know if there's power and shut down as needed.
Will getting power externally cause any problems on the USB connection to the PC?
Is power drawn involved in device discovery? Should I put a resistor there instead of just disconnecting?
Do I have to worry about different types of USB port (I think my server has USB 2, USB 3 and USB 3.1C... I plan to use the USB 2 one)?
FWIW, I do have a UPS. A JBR GUARD 600VA BIVOLT. But my country does not sell UPS with any sort of USB functionality outside of "power your entire data center" price point. And nobody will ship a brand new consumer one without the battery, which kill buying one from overseas. In the end, home servers have UPS just to get a power loss a little later.

What UPS do you have?

The answer contains Therefore, the USB VBUS is an important "side-band" signal in USB connect protocol.. Therefore, don't think the suggestion to use a USB flash drive will work. Are microcontroller development boards an option for you? The EK-TM4C1294XL has two USB 2 ports, and has jumpers for selecting how power is applied. With some software development it might be possible to use such a board to create a "USB AC power fail" alarm.

Rather then use a USB pen drive, have you considered using something else better suited for the task?   I can think of all manor of things, like looking for a device not UPS but on ethernet (maybe even the switch?)  or "pinging" a $5 esp8266 based wireless device like a mini "WIFI Mini Smart Switch"?

Also, the EK-TM4C1294XL has an Ethernet port, so could be programmed to send "power OK" message over the network. I.e. power the EK-TM4C1294XL off a USB charger and when the power fails the messages stop being sent. Do you have a spare Ethernet port, either on the PC on a network switch, which could be used for a "Ethernet AC power OK" message?

There shouldnt be any issues as long as you respect the power V and AMPs on USB. That said, why dont you use, I'll just assume, on back of your UPS there should be an usb? use cable to connect it directly to server, install its software on server, and set it to shut server on, IE i have mine set to shut server down on 15%.

@NickSlash https://jbrenergy.com.br/nobreaks-jbr-bivolt/jbr-guard-600va-bivolt/ it does have the ICs to drive the non-populated USB port and a header for "USB"...

@Danijel that's what I do in the US. Where I am there's no UPS option with any communication port whatsoever. Hence why I need this hack.

XY problem. The title and the explicit questions in the body are Y. You told us what X is. Almost always telling is better than not telling. Nevertheless the overall thread is untidy because the only answer (so far) is an extremely good idea for solving your problem (X), but it totally does not answer your question (Y). Before an answer that answers Y appears (and it may happen), you can rebuild the question, so it concentrates on X. Then the question and the existing answer will form a pretty useful pair.

For comparison: an example where an answer to Y came first and kinda blocked fixing the question: here.

@KamilMaciorowski I asked exactly what was in the title and provided context. People offered better solutions based on the context... And while I liked the alternative solution, you will see I have not accepted it in case someone do answer the original question. (i'm upvoting it and the comments because they ARE really good suggestions!)

So you want to keep the XY form, noted. In my opinion this attitude is not in the gist of Stack Exchange (which is: one problem per question; thus answers that solve different problems under one question indicate there is something "wrong"), but I won't fight. Standing down now.

@KamilMaciorowski you mean continue to accept Y answers for a X question? If you think we can edit the question to avoid Y answers please, do suggest something. Otherwise I don't understand what you are suggesting.

If the title and the main explicit question was "how can I detect power loss with just a dumb UPS?" or so, then the existing answer could be accepted and anyone with the same problem could find the question and benefit from it. For now it's easy for such person to miss the whole thread, unless he or she has the same idea as you had. "Will getting power externally cause any problems on the USB connection?" may be a separate question without context, so anyone with this exact question could benefit from answers that (hopefully) will appear, even if their context is different. (cont'd)

(cont'd) The two questions may be linked to each other. In particular, when asking "will getting power …?", you can emphasize you want exactly this to be answered, to avoid comments like "what is the real problem?" and attempts to solve the real problem. You write "the real problem is … and it's solved here (link), but I'm still interested in investigating this particular possible solution". Then everyone who wants help with X (and not necessarily with Y) will hopefully find the below answer about X; and everyone who wants help with Y (and not necessarily with X) will find the other question.

See this Q&A - Can the external power be supplied in one of the ports of the usb hub?.

Your plan is unsupported by the USB specification and may result in hardware damage.
Your plan is:


Disconnect the power pins from the USB connector.
Connect a USB charger to a mains outlet not covered by the battery backup power.
Connect the 5 V from that charger directly into the USB flash drive.


This gives us a matrix of 4 possible configurations:




PC powered
PC shutdown




Charger powered
A: Nominal operation
B: When the power comes back while the PC is still shutdown


Charger shutdown
C: Just after a power failure
D: Total power failure



Cases A and D are fine.
With case C, the computer provides 5V via the USB wire, but because VBUS is cut, nothing happens.
This leaves us with case B. In case B, the charger provides 5V/GND to the IC inside the USB stick. One thing USB 2.0 devices are supposed to do is feed back voltage via a resistor on D+ identifying that an USB 2.0 device is attached. The computer now receives this voltage even though the internal circuity doesn't have any power. This is a design situation that is not defined in any of USB certifications, and a chip that power applied to its data pin might enter a latch-up state during boot
If you look at the circuity of a mains powered USB hub, you will see that it has provisions to deal with this. Even on a hub that requires main power, VBUS from the upstream connection is not left floating, but goes towards the hub IC, where the IC detects the connection and only activates the USB pull up resistor when a voltage is applied
You need to mirror this in your device, you effectively need to make an AND gate that only enabled powered to the USB stick if power is present in both inputs. This only requires a few electronic components, for example with 3 resistors and 2 transistors you can make:

Link to schematic

You probably don't need any new hardware to do this, assuming that your computer is wired to a switch (it will probably work with Wi-Fi too) as soon as the switch loses power, the NIC in your computer will detect the link has dropped "Media disconnected" and you can trigger whatever action you want on that.

That's actually an extremely good idea! I have all the network gear in battery backup as well, but I guess one switch directly on mains won't hurt. Worst case i will have the switch startup time as a small "downtime" in case the energy just have a hiccup. Small price to pay i guess.

You could potentially split the difference between this idea and OPs original one and avoid short term network glitches by connecting a USB2 drive via an externally powered hub.  My powered hub shuts off immediately if external power is removed instead of attempting to run via PC power even with only a single low draw device (my mouse) connected.

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight that is even smarter! I'm adding the code for these ideas on https://github.com/gcb/dumb_ups  I confess i was already considering a second switch because i wanted to send network alerts when i lost power :) but a usb hub might be cheaper/lower power.

@gcb Another old school alternative with minimal hardware would be a USB Serial adapter and using the CTS input as a general purpose input. Tie it to +5v power derived from mains with a pull-down to the computers ground, and that should give you a signal you can monitor.

@gcb Another more creative solution would be to try and find a 9v ac power supply and a 50:1 transformer or even a resistor divider to generate a 0.18v AC signal, then feed that into an audio line input. If the tone disappears, then power is out.

To answer the USB question:

Will getting power externally cause any problems on the USB connection to the PC?

In general this will work perfectly fine. USB host detects the insertion of a new device based on a pull-up resistor on either D+ line (full speed and high speed devices) or D- line (low speed device). The host only includes maximum current limit for Vbus, it doesn't care about minimum current.
The device may care: some devices may stop responding to USB requests if they don't see any communication within a few seconds of power being applied, as they might enter a deep standby state. Typically though the PC should be able to automatically wake the device up with USB reset command. But because in your case you are powering the device on/off after the PC is already on, this shouldn't be an issue.
Regarding connection details:

Connect GND, D+ and D- to the PC
Connect GND and Vbus to the power adapter
Note that GND must connect to both the adapter and to PC. It's best to use a non-grounded (floating) adapter for this to avoid any ground current issues, but pretty much all USB wall warts are floating.

Edit: I agree with the concern that Ferrybig has brought up. This does not comply with USB specification, which says "The voltage source on the pull-up resistor must be derived from or controlled by the power supplied on the USB
cable such that when VBUS is removed, the pull-up resistor does not supply current on the data line to which it is
attached.". In practice most hosts probably have ESD diodes that clamp the input voltage to the supply line, but that is not required by the specification.

If you do not connect GND both to the adapter and to the PC, the voltages will be floating relative to each other and you will have a bad time.

A more recent answer from Ferrybig points out a potential problem when a USB2.0 devices connect D+ to voltage through a resistor while the computer is powered down, causing potential latch-up when it does power on: apparently the USB spec says it should only be doing this when getting power from the host, not its own internal power.  You might want to edit your answer to say something about that one way or another.

@PeterCordes Thanks for notifying, amended the answer.
